# Selecting an item in a combo cause a cyclic call

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I am writing a winform application.
On the form I have a Label and a combobox.
The combobox is populated with fonts names. When selecting a font from it, the label's font text is changing accordingly. When clicking on the label, the combobox's selecteditem is set accordingly.
The problem is when I am selecting the label, I get a cyclic call: I am setting the combobox item according to the font of the label, then the SelectedIndexChanged is fired which is in charge to set the font name of the label (ChangeLabelFont).
So the label font is again updated while it is the trigger of all those calls.

```
private void FontToolStripComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectedLabel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ChangeLabelFont(FontNameToolStripComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), FontSizeToolStripComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }

private void SelectLabel(Point location)
    {
        SetComboBoxesFont(_selectedLabel.Font.Name, _selectedLabel.Font.Size);
    }

private void SetComboBoxesFont(string name, float size)
    {
        FontNameToolStripComboBox.SelectedItem = name;
        FontSizeToolStripComboBox.SelectedItem = size;
    }

private void ChangeLabelFont(string name, string size)
    {
        if (_selectedLabel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily(name);
        float fontSize = float.Parse(size);

        _selectedLabel.Font = new Font(fontFamily, fontSize);
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent this cyclic call? Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: well, what did you expect? What's your actual question, anyway?

Comment: thanks, I updated the post

Comment: I think that's a not difficult one. In your FontToolStripComboBox_SelectedIndexChangedfont, check if the label font is the same as the one you're trying to change and don't do it if the answer is yes :)

Comment: Well, setting a flag or checking the current font is not what I was expecting as solving the problem. Maybe there is another event that can help to prevent cyclic call

Comment: I don't think there's another way..the events are going to be fired everytime,so you must check when to run or not run your logic

Comment: We all know a classic example of MS word. They have a same case when selecting a font or selecting the text. I don't think they have a cyclic call, use a flag or checking the font. There are a lot of properties such as color, style, indentation, rtl, alignment....

Comment: Well...then let's wait for a MS word coder to tell us how they do it ;) Using events, i don't see other way to do it...

Comment: Just because Word does something does not mean you just include it's tag. `ms-word` tag is for questions writing plugins and interop code with Word.

Answer (score 1):

There is something missing in the code you're showing. I'd like to see the `ChangeLabelFont` method as well as the handler for the "select label" event. But I suppose it's the `SelectLabel` method in the end. So how about using a member flag:

```
private bool m_bInhibitCycle = false;
private void SelectLabel(Point location)
{
    if (m_bInhibitCycle) return;
    m_bInhibitCycle = true;
    SetComboBoxesFont(_selectedLabel.Font.Name, _selectedLabel.Font.Size);
    m_bInhibitCycle = false;
}
```

Comment: I updated my post adding ChangeLabelFont method. Well, setting a flag or checking the current font is not what I was expecting as solving the problem. Maybe there is another event that can help to prevent cyclic call

Comment: @ehh I don't think so. If you call methods in a cyclic way, who should prevent that, maybe it's just what you want to do. Well you could remove and add one of the handlers when the other one is called, but that would be the same as my solution but a little more complicated and less readable.